# How to use get_media_embedded_in_content function

Tags: functions, shortcode, oembed

I am trying to figure out how to use this new WordPress function.

```
get_media_embedded_in_content (string $content);
```

[The documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_media_embedded_in_content/) says, "a string that might contain media data" but that is too vague. I've tried this below but it doesn't work. Can anyone provide an example?

```
get_media_embedded_in_content (string 'get_the_content');
```

Example:

```
add_shortcode( 'pslider', 'pslider_shortcode' );
function pslider_shortcode($atts){
  ob_start();
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'type' => 'post',
    'mode' => 'fade',
    'category' => 'uncategorized',
    'width' => '1499px',
    'height' => 'auto',
    'num' => 9,
    'adaptive' => 'true',
    'speed' => '1000',
    'auto' => 'false',
    'pause' => '4000',
    'loop' => 'true',
    'video' => 'true',
    'thumbs' => 'false'
    ), $atts));   

  echo  '<div id="tslider">
  <div class="pslider">
  <ul>'; 
    $loop = new WP_Query();
    $loop->query( array( 'post_type' => $type, 'showposts' => $num ) );



  while ( $loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
  $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
  $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'slider-full', true);
  $imgUrl = $img[0];

  $image_title = get_the_title();
  $image_caption = button_excerpt(140);
  $image_description = button_excerpt(140);
  $permalink = get_permalink();
  $media = get_media_embedded_in_content( apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ));

  echo  "<li>";   


echo "Content: <br/>";

echo $media;

  echo "<br /> end content";
  print_r($media);
  var_dump($media);
  //echo  "<img src='$img[0]' style='width: $width; height: $height;'/>";        


  echo  "</li>\n";

  endwhile; wp_reset_query();


  echo  '</ul>
  </div>
  </div> </div>'; 


$output = ob_get_clean();
return $output;

}//end function
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`get_media_embedded_in_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_media_embedded_in_content/) function is a handy helper function, though it doesn't seem to be used in the core (ver. 4.2.2).

### Regular expression:

To understand the [`get_media_embedded_in_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_media_embedded_in_content/) function, we must understand the following regular expression:

```
#<(?P<tag>video|audio|object|embed|iframe)[^<]*?(?:>[\s\S]*?<\/(?P=tag)>|\s*\/>)#
```

There are many online *regular-expression* tools to help us with that.

Like this one:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/XO8EM_Xtd02Wtvrn)

We note that it's possible to label a capturing group `(...)` with 
`(?P<Label>...)` and match it with `(?P=Label)`.

### Example:

Let's consider the following string:

```
$content = '
    My page: <iframe src="page.html"></iframe> 
    My favorite song: <audio src="song.mp3"/>
    My old car: <img src="car.jpg"/>
';
```

How do we extract the HTML code for the embedded media?

We use:

```
$media = get_media_embedded_in_content( $content );
```

where the default content media tags are `video`, `audio`, `object`, `embed` and `iframe`.

Let's view the output of:

```
print_r( $media );
```

In this case it's:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <iframe src="page.html"></iframe>
    [1] => <audio src="song.mp3"/>
)
```

We note that the `img` tag isn't included, as expected.

### oEmbeds:

If we need to catch the oembeds in the content, we should use for example:

```
$media = get_media_embedded_in_content( 
    apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() )
);
```

instead of:

```
$media = get_media_embedded_in_content( get_the_content() );
```

in the loop, because `get_the_content()` returns the unfiltered content.

### Filter:

We can control the allowed content media tags, with the `media_embedded_in_content_allowed_types` filter.

Example:

```
/**
 * Remove 'object' from the allowed content media types.
 * 
 * @param  array $types Array of allowed types
 * @return array $types Array of allowed types
 */
add_filter( 'media_embedded_in_content_allowed_types', function( $types )
{
    // Let's remove 'object'
    if( isset( $types['object'] ) )
        unset( $types['object'] );

    return $types;
} );
```

Comment: I just noticed your [tag:oembed] tag, are you trying to catch the *oembeds* in the content? You don't mention this in your question. Notice that `get_the_content()` returns the unfiltered content, so try `apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() )` instead. You're using the word "hook" when you should be using "function". Please update your question accordingly and elaborate further on "it doesn't work". Thanks. @jkcoding

Comment: Most media in WordPress is converted to oEmbeds so I thought it will be nice tag to add. We came up with the same conclusions as you and again it doesn't work. The output is a php error - array to string conversion. I also did a var dump and got array(0) {}

Comment: It works as expected when I tested it within a loop with one of the default themes activated. Please update your question with the content example your are testing, and where you've placed the function => a testable code example. Thanks. @jkcoding

Comment: I added the entire shortcode function to the question now.

Comment: The PHP error you get says it all: you are using an array as string. Note that you are echoing `$media` when `$media` is an array, not a string. Instead you should echoing `$media[0]`, `$media[1]`, etc. If you read @birgire's answer you will know why `$media` in your code is an array with the collection of all media elements found in the content passed to `get_media_embedded_in_content()`.

Comment: @cybmeta now you get Undefined offset: 0 as the error, again I think there is something wrong with the function or neither of us is using it properly.

Comment: @birgie now what could be the issue? I tried it with $media[0] and it still gives an error of undefined offset.

Comment: print_r($media) gives an empty array as well.

Comment: @cybmeta the first post is just an oembed so there is media in the posts.

Comment: @cybmeta The developer I worked with solved the problem using ob_star() and ob_end_flush() around the function. I thought it wasn't necessary, but we needed to use it again because we had another oembed function interfering. Some of them having array 0 was justified because it had no media, thanks for your help.

Comment: ok glad to hear it worked for you in the end ;-)  ps: you should use `wp_reset_postdata()` instead of `wp_reset_query()` in your code example @jkcoding